# How to pass an array of objects from one page to another using angular

Tags: angular

Can someone help me know how to send an array of objects from first to second page using route on button click, this is my array structure:

```
​Array[{ attributeName: "name0", attributeValue: "val0" }
      ​{ attributeName: "name1", attributeValue: "val1" }
​      { attributeName: "name2", attributeValue: "val2" }]
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing objects by routing is quite limited. Using a service is a better option.
You can create say `DataService` class as angular service and pass it around your App via Dependency Injection.
You can attach the relative data to the `DataService` injected via DI and retrieve it in the other page's component.

Refer https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service as well